# Arranging Product Details on Shop Page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am attempting to edit my Woocommerce site (locally) and rotate the product cards horizontally. For an example of what I'm trying to do, check out B&H Photo's layout. I'm using Foundation framework with the JointsWP starter theme.

I have the WooCommerce Compare Products PRO and WooCommerce WishLists Plugins installed.

I made an example product to show what my problem is (forgot to add a rating but it's displayed under the price):

[image: example Woocommerce product card]

---

**What I've tried so far**

1. I've tried using the hooks from the original content-product:

   - do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
   - do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
   - do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

then:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
```

2. I added the actions back with different priorities.
3. I've tried moving each item's div column in content-product.php above and below each other.
4. I've tried copy/pasting the code from each template (add-to-cart.php, rating.php, price.php) instead of referencing the function.

> *It works if I delete the wishlist, compare and cart button code.*

Here's the code from the content-product.php:

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<div class="row">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <div class="small-12 columns panel">

            <div class="small-3 columns">

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail(); ?>

            </div>

            <div class="small-6 columns">

                <h3><small><?php the_title(); ?></small></h3>

                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>

            </div>

            <div class="small-3 columns panel end">

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_price' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_price(); ?>

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_rating' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_rating(); ?>

                <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php echo add_query_arg( array('add-to-wishlist-itemid' => $product->id), $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
                    <?php $wishlists->add_to_wishlist_button(); ?>
                </form>

                <?php if ( function_exists('woo_add_compare_button' ) ) echo woo_add_compare_button(); ?>

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

---

I forgot to mention that I also removed Woocommerce styles with the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'wc_dequeue_styles' );
function wc_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );        // Remove the gloss
unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] );         // Remove the layout
unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

Comment: Third party plugins are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Try the support forums at [WooThemes](http://support.woothemes.com), or [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce). I'd also encourage you to lend your support to the proposed [WooCommerce Q&A site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80132/woocommerce) on StackExchange, if you haven't already.

Comment: Ok, sounds good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I was working on another section of the site and was browsing the Foundation Docs.

I saw the ability to push/pull columns and decided to give it a try. It worked.

Here's the code I used:

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<div class="row">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <div class="small-12 columns panel">

            <div class="small-3 columns">

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail(); ?>

            </div>

            <div class="small-6 small-pull-3 columns">

                <h3><small><?php the_title(); ?></small></h3>

                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>

            </div>

            <div class="small-3 small-push-6 columns panel end">

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_price' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_price(); ?>

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_rating' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_rating(); ?>

                <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php echo add_query_arg( array('add-to-wishlist-itemid' => $product->id), $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
                    <?php $wishlists->add_to_wishlist_button(); ?>
                </form>

                <?php if ( function_exists('woo_add_compare_button' ) ) echo woo_add_compare_button(); ?>

                <?php if ( function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ) ) echo woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```